# haskell: creating list of records

Tags: haskell, winghci

How to create a list of records in haskell

I have a Record

```
data TestList = Temp1 (String,[String])
          | Temp2 (String,[(String,String)])
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I am creating a list of records

```
testLists :: [TestList]
testLists =  [minBound..maxBound]
```

When I run, it throws me an error.

```
No instance for (Enum TestList)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence `minBound .. maxBound'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Enum TestList)
    In the expression: [minBound .. maxBound]
    In an equation for `testLists': testLists = [minBound .. maxBound]
```

It gives me a possible fix but I don't understand what it means. can anyone explain it and tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `minBound` and `maxBound` unless you declare beforehand what they mean for your type (which by the way is not a [record type](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax)). You must, as the error also tells you, declare the type as an `instance` of `Bounded`. Without knowledge of what your type is to represent, it's impossible to say what such a declaration should look like exactly, but its general form is

```
instance Bounded TestList where
  minBound = ...
  maxBound = ...
```

(Fill in the `...`)

Comment: I understand the problem. But one thing is that its a list of size 0 to infinite.. So how can I define the minBound and maxBound.

Comment: @veda: you can't write a generic instance that would make sense for all uses of a list, however you can write one which is sensible for your problem domain, presuming that you do know an upper bound in advance.

Comment: @larsmans: I disagree with your statements. 1) there are `Enum` types that have an infinite number of values (e.g. `Integer`) 2) `maxBound` has nothing to do with `Enum` (it is part of `Bounded`) 3) Nevertheless, I could still imagine there being a type that is bounded and still has an infinite number of values "in the middle"

Comment: Where I said `Enum` I meant `Bounded`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell it how to enumerate values of type `TestList`. Even if it understands what `minBound` and `maxBound` are, it doesn't know how to discover what all of the values in between are (in order to create a list with those values).

By adding an instance declaration for `Enum TestList`, you would basically be instructing it on how to enumerate values, so it would be able to construct that sequence for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.  First, you'll need to create an `Enum` instance (as others have said).  An `Enum` instance is required because you've used the special enumeration syntax `[ a .. b]`.

Once you've created the `Enum` instance, you'll also need to write an instance for `Bounded` because you've used `minBound` and `maxBound`.

Usually you can tell Haskell compilers to derive both of these instances, however that won't work here because neither Lists nor Strings have instances for either type class.  What value should `maxBound :: String` have, anyway?  You could always make a longer string, or add another element to a list.  Since you can't derive the instances, you'll have to manually write the `Enum` instance as in larsmans answer and similarly a `Bounded` instance.